# convert TextReader to XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, io, xmlreader, textreader

I have a function that gets `TextReader` I want to use it as `XmlReader:

```
    private void myFunc(TextReader textReader)
    {
        XmlReader _xml;
        _xml=?
    }
```

Is there a way to convert `TextReader` to `XmlReader`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `XmlReader.Create(TextReader)` for creating the new instance of XmlReader

[XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader);
```

From the [`docs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543.aspx)